# Snake game, start

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

### **I have fixed the errors but I am still unable to get the game to start**

This is a snake game and I can not get it to start. When I try to run it on Eclipse it keeps giving me

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Snake.createSnake(Snake.java:110)
at Snake.<init>(Snake.java:95)
at Driver.main(Driver.java:6)
```

I just need someone to please explain and help me fix this. I have asked numerous friends and no one that I know can help me fix it.

```
public class Driver {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Snake game = new Snake();
    }

}
```

Below is this Snake class.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;



@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class Snake extends JFrame implements KeyListener, Runnable{

JPanel gamePanel, scorePanel;
JButton extraFood;
JTextArea textAreaScore;
int x = 500;
int y = 250;
int minSnake = 3;
int directionx = 1;
int directiony = 0;
int speed = 50;
int difference = 0;
int oldx = 0;
int oldy = 0;
int score = 0;
boolean food = false;
boolean runLeft = false;
boolean runRight = true;
boolean runUp = true;
boolean runDown = true;
boolean bonusFlag = true;
Random ran = new Random();
JButton[] bc = new JButton[200];
int[] bx = new int[300];
int[] by = new int[300];
Thread myThread;
Point[] bp = new Point[300];
Point bonusp = new Point();


//initializing values
public void Values() {
    minSnake = 3;
    directionx = 10;
    directiony = 0;
    difference = 0;
    score = 0;
    food = false;
    runLeft = false;
    runRight = true;
    runUp = true;
    runDown = true;
    bonusFlag = true;
}

//sets layout of game
public Snake() {
    getContentPane().setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    gamePanel = new JPanel();
    gamePanel.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    gamePanel.setBounds(6, 6, 438, 223);
    getContentPane().add(gamePanel);
    gamePanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0, 0, 0));

    scorePanel = new JPanel();
    scorePanel.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    scorePanel.setBounds(6, 241, 438, 31);
    getContentPane().add(scorePanel);
    scorePanel.setLayout(null);

    textAreaScore = new JTextArea("Your score is:" + score);
    textAreaScore.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    textAreaScore.setBounds(0, 0, 303, 31);
    scorePanel.add(textAreaScore);

    //Exit Game button
    JButton btnExitGame = new JButton("Exit Game");
    btnExitGame.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        }
    });
    btnExitGame.setBounds(315, 0, 117, 29);
    scorePanel.add(btnExitGame);

    btnExitGame.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);

        }

    });
    setVisible(true);
    createSnake();
    extraFood = new JButton();
    extraFood.setEnabled(false);

    addKeyListener(this);
    //This starts the game
    myThread = new Thread(this);
    myThread.start();
}

   //Creates snake
public void createSnake() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        bc[i] = new JButton("b" + i);
        bc[i].setEnabled(false);
        gamePanel.add(bc[i]);
        bc[i].setBounds(bx[0], by[0], 10, 10);
        bx[i + 1] = bx[i] - 10;
        by[i + 1] = by[i];

    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
void reset(){
    Values();
    gamePanel.removeAll();
    myThread.stop();
    createSnake();
    textAreaScore.setText("Your score is: " + score);

     myThread = new Thread(this);
     myThread.start();

}

//As snake eats food, it grows
void snakeGrow(){
    bc[minSnake] = new JButton();
    bc[minSnake].setEnabled(false);
    gamePanel.add(bc[minSnake]);

    int a = 10 + (10 * ran.nextInt(48));
    int b = 10 + (10 * ran.nextInt(23));

    bx[minSnake] = a;
    by[minSnake] = b;
    bc[minSnake].setBounds(a, b, 10, 10);
    minSnake++;
}

//Snake moving logic
void moveForward() {
    for (int i = 0; i < minSnake; i++) {
        bp[i] = bc[i].getLocation();
    }

    bx[0] += directionx;
    by[0] += directiony;
    bc[0].setBounds(bx[0], by[0], 10, 10);

    for (int i = 1; i < minSnake; i++) {
        bc[i].setLocation(bp[i - 1]);
    }

    if (bx[0] == x) {
        bx[0] = 10;
    } else if (bx[0] == 0) {
        bx[0] = x - 10;
    } else if (by[0] == y) {
        by[0] = 10;
    } else if (by[0] == 0) {
        by[0] = y - 10;
    }

    if (bx[0] == bx[minSnake - 1] && by[0] == by[minSnake - 1]) {
        food = false;
        score += 1;
        textAreaScore.setText("Your score is: " + score);
        if (score % 50 == 0 && bonusFlag == true) {
            gamePanel.add(extraFood);
            extraFood.setBounds((10 * ran.nextInt(50)), (10 * ran.nextInt(25)), 15, 15);
            bonusp = extraFood.getLocation();
            bonusFlag = false;
        }
    }

    if (bonusFlag == false) {
        if (bonusp.x <= bx[0] && bonusp.y <= by[0] && bonusp.x + 10 >= bx[0] && bonusp.y +
    10 >= by[0]) {
            gamePanel.remove(extraFood);
            score += 100;
            textAreaScore.setText("Your score is: " + score);
            bonusFlag = true;
        }
    }

    if (food == false) {
        snakeGrow();
        food = true;
    } else {
        bc[minSnake - 1].setBounds(bx[minSnake - 1], by[minSnake - 1], 10, 10);
    }



    gamePanel.repaint();
    extracted();
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void extracted() {
    show();
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    //Move to the left when player presses the left arrow key
    if (runLeft == true && e.getKeyCode() == 37) {
        directionx = -10; //Moves to the left by 10 pixels
        directiony = 0;
        runRight = false;     
        runUp = true;      
        runDown = true;      
    }
    //Move up when player presses the up arrow key
    if (runUp == true && e.getKeyCode() == 38) {
        directionx = 0;
        directiony = -10; //Moves up by 10 pixels
        runDown = false;     
        runRight = true;      
        runLeft = true;      
    }
   //Move to the right when the player presses the right arrow key
    if (runRight == true && e.getKeyCode() == 39) {
        directionx = +10; //Moves right by 10 pixels
        directiony = 0;
        runLeft = false;
        runUp = true;
        runDown = true;
    }
    //Move down when the player presses the down arrow key
    if (runDown == true && e.getKeyCode() == 40) {
        directionx = 0;
        directiony = +10; //Moves down by 10 pixels
        runUp = false;
        runRight = true;
        runLeft = true;
    }
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
}

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
}

public void run() {
    for (;;) {

        //Moves the snake forward
        moveForward();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(speed);
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Well, you've got the exact line number where the problem is. What's going on on line 110? My guess is you forgot to initialize something. You're using Eclipse, so debugging it should be a snap.

Comment: @Frecklefoot This is actually kind of confusing to debug due to the nature of variable shadowing and scope especially for a person first learning programming. But you are correct in saying they should have just tried to debug it themselves first.

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that you're not setting the global `gamePanel` variable in your constructor just a local version of it. Remove the `JPanel` in front of the variable initialization and it should work.

Same applies to your `scorePanel` and `textAreaScore` variables.

Answer (score 3):

You declared view objects (i.e. gamePanel, scorePanel, extraFood, textAreaScore) as member variables of your class Snake, but then declared local variables of the same name in your constructor.

Member variables:

```
JPanel gamePanel, scorePanel;
JButton extraFood;
JTextArea textAreaScore;
```

Local variables:

```
public Snake() {
    ...
    JPanel gamePanel = new JPanel();

    ...
    JPanel scorePanel = new JPanel();
    ...

    JTextArea textAreaScore = new JTextArea("Your score is:" + score);
    ...
```

Change the constructor to instantiate your member variables like so:

```
public Snake() {
    ...
    this.gamePanel = new JPanel();

    ...
    this.scorePanel = new JPanel();
    ...

    this.textAreaScore = new JTextArea("Your score is:" + score);
    ...
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is here:
You defined the global variable:

```
JPanel gamePanel, scorePanel;
JTextArea textAreaScore;
```

But you defined dupplicate in:

```
public Snake() {
    JPanel gamePanel = new JPanel();
    ...
    JPanel scorePanel = new JPanel();
    ...
    JTextArea textAreaScore = new JTextArea("Your score is:" + score);
    ...
}
```

So, change them to:

```
public Snake() {
        gamePanel = new JPanel();
        ...
        scorePanel = new JPanel();
        ...
        textAreaScore = new JTextArea("Your score is:" + score);
        ...
    }
```

That's it.

Answer (score 2):

You are [shadowing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4.1) `gamePanel` in the constructor of `Snake`. Replace

```
JPanel gamePanel = new JPanel();
```

with

```
gamePanel = new JPanel();
```

The variables `scorePanel` and `textAreaScore` have the same issue.

---

Side issues:

- Don't use `KeyListeners` in Swing applications. They were not designed to be used with Swing applications. Use [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) instead.
- Similarly don't use raw Threads for Swing applications, use a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) instead

Comment: he does this in the constructor.

Comment: ummm i only downvoted once. so ya.

Comment: And the scorePanel, as well. And extraFood. And textAreaScore.

Comment: @Ryan Amos: `extraFood` is OK